# helper sometimes called twice in meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have this helper, and sometimes its called twice first time the slug is undefined the second time its okay, how to prevent helper to be called twice?

```
shareurl: ->
    console.log "helper"

    campId = Session.get('campaign_id')

    Meteor.call 'getCampaignSlug', campId, (e, resp) ->
      console.log e if e
      console.log resp
      slug = resp[0]
      campaignId = resp[1]
      Session.set('slug' + campId, slug)

    slug = Session.get('slug' + campId)
    #slug = "test"

    console.log Meteor.absoluteUrl "" + Meteor.user()._id + '/' + slug
    return Meteor.absoluteUrl "" + Meteor.user()._id + '/' + slug
```

In the template its called once.But in console i see that sometimes its called twice.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right draft-send mr10" type="button" data-shareurl="{{shareurl}}" data-step="1" data-intro="Click here to send your campaign" data-position="left">Send</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with coffeescript but try to wrap `campId = Session.get('campaign_id')` like so:

```
if(campId = Session.get('campaign_id')){
  //do my stuff
}
```

Then if your session variable is undefined, nothing will be processed.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

It gets called twice because when it's called the first time, you make a method call. When the result of that method call is processed (note: the first call to this helper has returned at this time), you change a session variable this helper depends on, and therefor this helper is called again.

**[NOTE]**

So, doesn't this result in an infinite loop? No, because the second time the helper gets called, you set the session variable to the same value as before, and that causes no re-runs.

**[/NOTE]**

So what's the solution? This can be handled in different ways (but none great, I'm afraid), but if you have a helper returning the value of `Session.get('slug' + Session.get('campaign_id'))`, you can use this helper in a `#if` block expression to see if it's been assigned a value yet or not, and inside this `#if` block expression you call your `shareurl`.